# V-model not binding in the DOM element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

Here is the code that I wrote and the issue is the v-model is not binding the data in the dom, the axios I am using is returning values but its not binding in the dom :

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex md4 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <v-card class="card" color="brown">
          <v-card-title class="headline grey--text">Your Card Details</v-card-title>
          <v-flex ma-2>
            <v-form class="form" ref="form" mt-2>
              <v-text-field v-model="info.name"></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field v-model="info.userName"></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field v-model="info.card"></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field v-model="info.expireDate"></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field v-model="info.cvv"></v-text-field>
              <v-btn @click="submit" flat color="success">Submit</v-btn>
              <v-btn @click="reset" flat color="error">Reset</v-btn>
            </v-form>
          </v-flex>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      info: [],
      valid: true
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("https://localhost:44311/api/payment-access")
      .then(res => this.info = res.data);
  },
  methods: {
    reset() {
      this.$refs.form.reset();
    },
    submit() {
      axios.get("https://localhost:44311/api/payment-access").then(res => {
        this.info = res.data;
        console.log(this.info);
        console.log("Yippy");
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.card {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: please provide the code as text

Comment: You define your `info: []` as array, but later you use it as object. You should define it from the start with `info: {name: '', userName: '', card: '', ...}`, where you need to specify all fields that will be used as models. Read more about [Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I tried to upload the code itself but I couldn't align it well, I a

Comment: try to paste it here https://pastebin.com and give me the link and i will edit your question by formatting it

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I tried to upload the code itself but I couldn't make the alignment right, so pls bear with me, and kindly provide solution If you can,@ljubadr I declare it as an array but when I assign the response.data to the info property once the promise returned, It will work, but for some reason which I dont know its not working now.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim here is the link https://pastebin.com/uK68kg4N

Comment: @aspiring_programmer it's done

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, thanks, how to do that, I tried for half an hour, It wouldn't allow me

Comment: click *`ctrl+M`* a new UI will be shown so paste your code to the corresponding sections

Comment: I tried, anyway thanks, did you find where I made mistake in the code

Comment: did you try the solution given by @ljubadr ?

Answer (score 1):

Vue doesn't do deep level binding until you declare it that way.
@Ijubadr tried to explain the same it.

Declare info in your data() in the script like this. An object not array

```
info: {name: '', userName: '', card: '', expireDate: '', cvv: ''}
```

assign your incoming data from axios accordingly. hint! something like below:

```
this.info = {
  name: data[0],
  userName: data[1],
  card: data[2],
  expireDate: data[3],
  cvv: data[4]
 }
```

*fill the above info object according to incoming data case array/object.
It should work

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks giving me the credit, but you can remove it and add the link to the docs [Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: ljubadr  @Rahul Roy thanks, i have done binding like the way I did in the question, it went well, but when I console log(this.info) it throw an error, thanks again